# Buffering based on topography in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, buffer, topography, terrain

I need to do a buffer based on the real terrain.
Like 500 meters from a polyline on all sides.
I have DEM (SRTM) of the terrain.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  It's a good idea to take the site tour to understand how the site works and how to write a good question. What research have you found and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, you can create a buffer based on terrain.  Here is a link to a tool to create buffers based on a surface model.
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/116656

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.